# How to load list only after FutureBuilder gets snapshot.data?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I have a JSON method that returns a `List` after it is completed,

```
Future<List<Feed>> getData() async {
  List<Feed> list;
  String link =
      "https://example.com/json";
  var res = await http.get(link);
  if (res.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = json.decode(res.body);
    var rest = data["feed"] as List;
    list = rest.map<Feed>((json) => Feed.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
  return list;
}
```

I then call this, in my `initState()` which contains a list hello, that will filter out the JSON list, but it shows me a `null` list on the screen first and after a few seconds it loads the list.

```
    getData().then((usersFromServer) { 
          setState(() {.   //Rebuild once it fetches the data
hello = usersFromServer
          .where((u) => (u.category.userJSON
              .toLowerCase()
              .contains('hello'.toLowerCase())))
          .toList();
            users = usersFromServer;
            filteredUsers = users;
          });
        });
```

This is my `FutureBuilder` that is called in `build()` method, however if I supply the hello list before the return statement, it shows me that the method `where()` was called on null (the list method that I am using to filter out `hello()` )

```
FutureBuilder(
            future: getData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return snapshot.data != null ?
                Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
                      SliverGrid(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
    childAspectRatio: 4.0,
  ),
  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
    (BuildContext context, int index) {
      return Container(
        child: puzzle[0],
      );
    },
    childCount: 1,
  ),
)
                    ]),
                  ],
                )
               :
               CircularProgressIndicator();
              
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your getData method multiple times. Don't do that. Your UI waits for one call and your code for the other. That's a mess. Call it *once* and wait for *that* call.

You need to define the future to wait for in your state:

```
Future<void> dataRetrievalAndFiltering;
```

Then in your `initstate`, assign the whole operation to this future:

(note that I removed the setState completely, it's not needed here anymore)

```
dataRetrievalAndFiltering = getData().then((usersFromServer) { 
      hello = usersFromServer.where((u) => (u.category.userJSON.toLowerCase().contains('hello'.toLowerCase()))).toList();
        users = usersFromServer;
        filteredUsers = users;
      
    });
```

Now your `FurtureBuilder` can actually wait *for that specific future*, not for a new Future you generate by calling your method again:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: dataRetrievalAndFiltering,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Now you have one Future, that you can wait for.

Comment: Hi, so I made the changes as you suggested however my future doesn't return the snapshot.data and is stuck on the CircularProgressIndicator()

Comment: Yeah, you are right. What is it what you want to show in that list? The users? The Feeds? You need to return that in your `.then()` and make the `Future<void>` into a `Future<List<?>>` with the `?` being the type you want to show in the list.

Comment: Alternatively, you could query `snapshot.connectionState` to show your progress indicator, since we don't return anything from the future, we write it in variables. So all we need is just the waiting part.

Comment: Ok so what I did is, I removed the .then parameter from the Future and directly called snapshot.data for hello, users & filteredUsers and it started working! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This response is a little too late to help you, but for anyone wondering how to load a Future and use any of it's data to set other variables without having the issue of saving it in a variable, and then calling setState() again and loading your future again, you can, as @nvoigt said, set a variable of the Future in your state, then you can call the .then() function inside the addPostFrameCallback() function to save the result, and finally using the future variable in your FutureBuilder like this.

```
class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  ...
  late MyFutureObject yourVariable;
  late Future<MyFutureObject> _yourFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _yourFuture = Database().yourFuture();

    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _yourFuture.then((result) {
        yourVariable = result;
        // Execute anything else you need to with your variable data.
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _yourFuture,
      builder: ...
    );
  }
}

dynamic doSomeStuffWithMyVariable() {
  // Do some stuff with `yourVariable`
}
```

So, the advantage of this is that you can use the data loaded in the future outside the scope of the FutureBuilder, and only loading it once.

In my case, I needed to get a map of objects from my future, then the user could select some of those objects, save them on a map and make some calculations based on that selection. But as selecting that data called setState() in order to update the UI, I wasn't able to do so without having to write a complicated logic to save the user selection properly in the map, and having to call the future again outside the scope of the FutureBuilder to get it's data for my other calculations.

With the example above, you can load your future only once, and use the snapshot data outside the scope of the FutureBuilder without having to call the future again.

I hope I was clear enough with this example. If you have any doubts I will gladly clarify them.